# Ethernet.begin() only works with SD Card removed - why?

Tags: arduino, software, ethernet

When I run this code on my [W5100 Ethernet Shield](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield):

```
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };  

void setup() {
  Ethernet.begin(mac);
}
```

it only works **when the SD Card was removed** from the shield!

---

It took me days to find this error. With SD Card installed only the *full begin setup* works:

```
Ethernet.begin(mac, ip, dns, gateway, subnet);
```

The [official documentation of `Ethernet.begin()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/EthernetBegin) says nothing about this problem. Why does it only fully work with SD Card removed? Is this a "documentation bug"?

Comment: What version of the shield do you have?

Comment: If you found an answer you should post it @powtac, not put it in your question. Instead make an answer to your own question.

Comment: @Kortuk He's looking for where it's documented / why it happens, not a workaround.

Comment: What operating system are you using, @powtac?

Comment: @taco I'm using Win7 64 with Arduino IDE 1.0.4

Answer (score 7):

According to the [Arduino Ethernet Shield page](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoEthernetShield):

> Note that because the W5100 and SD card share the SPI bus, only one
>   can be active at a time. If you are using both peripherals in your
>   program, this should be taken care of by the corresponding libraries.
>   If you're not using one of the peripherals in your program, however,
>   you'll need to explicitly deselect it. To do this with the SD card,
>   set pin 4 as an output and write a high to it. For the W5100, set
>   digital pin 10 as a high output.

And if you're using the first version of the board:

> The original revision of the shield contained a full-size SD card
>   slot; this is not supported.

Comment: So, to use both, you have to change the status of pins 4 and 10 every time you switch?

Comment: It appears so. Although "this should be taken care of by the corresponding libraries" makes me believe that should be done automatically with the built-in libs.

Answer (score 3):

You can report bugs with the codebase [here](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/search?q=Ethernet.begin) (it looks like they moved from Google code to Github).

Based on [this report](https://code.google.com/p/arduino/issues/detail?id=62&can=1&q=Ethernet.begin) it sounds like a third party added the DHCP support, so I would report the issue to make sure it isn't a bug.

It looks like maybe you are using bad documentation, based on [this report](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/880).

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/pull/1334

Answer (score -1):

Kevin Mark gave very good answer why your ethernet shield don' work with SD. Here is answer what to do to make it working.

[How to avoid SD Card and W1500 SPI mixup on the Ethernet Shield?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67212/how-to-avoid-sd-card-and-w1500-spi-mixup-on-the-ethernet-shield)

Comment: This more along the lines of a comment and link only answer which is frowned upon here.  If you want to contribute, post more information and of course give attribution.